# jsPDF brings previous print information

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have this unformatted table [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylBBR.png) that has 3 rows and 2 columns. The second column has a barcode generated from the information in the first column

When changing the table model, removing some columns: PDF generation happens like this: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GDUL.png) overwriting only the information that changed and keeping "dirt" from the previous generation.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: you should add your code to your question

Comment: I tried to reproduce it on a pen but it worked right. [HERE](https://codepen.io/jonathanmribeiro/pen/LLwWxW)

Comment: @ЄвгенійБагмуцький answer please so I can close it.

Comment: how can i answer if u say it now works right?) looks like there is no question then